# Ich liebe (es) + Infinitiv

Tags: grammaticality, infinitive, expletiva

> *Ich liebe es, zu malen.*
>
> *Ich liebe, zu malen.*

Sind beide Sätze richtig, oder nur der mit *es*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Korrekt ist der Satz mit *es*. Warum?

*Lieben* ist ein transitives Verb; es benötigt ein Objekt (*ich liebe was?*). Möchte man es dennoch mit einem Verb verbinden (*malen*), braucht man das *es*, das als Objekt fungiert und mit einem Nebensatz erweitert wird (*zu malen*).

Comment: Ich dachte, dass der Infinitiv selbst auch als Objekt auftreten kann. Danke.

Comment: @tom Diese Art von *Valenz* ist abhängig vom verwendeten Verb. "Ich hoffe, die Prüfung zu bestehen" ist korrekt, "Ich liebe, Prüfungen zu bestehen" nicht - bei "lieben" muß das Nominalobjekt ausgedrückt werden. Leider kann man diese Unterschiede nur auswendig lernen.

Comment: »Ich liebe malen« (oder: *Malen*?) geht aber auch, d.h, wenn das *zu* weggelassen wird, ists wieder in Ordnung.

Comment: Richtig, das geht auch. Dann fungiert nämlich das Substantiv "das Malen" als Objekt von "lieben". Wenn Du "malen" als Verb verwenden willst, funktioniert der Satz so allerdings nicht.

Answer (score -3):

Ja, beides ist richtig. Nur die Interpunktion ist falsch.

Ich liebe es, zu malen.

Ich liebe zu malen. (Bei einer nackten Infinitivphrase kein Komma!)

Das Satzglied ›zu malen‹ kann als Objekt oder auch als Adverbiale interpretiert werden. In beiden Fällen darf jedenfalls kein Komma gesetzt werden.

---

Ich sage das nur ungern, aber wenn jemand mit Valenz und Agens kommt, ist das ein triftiges Indiz für ideologisches Getue. Die geisteswissenschaftliche Satzlehre sollte bei praktischen Grammatikfragen am besten überhört werden.

›Ich liebe Malen‹ funktioniert auch. In dem Fall ist die Großschreibung vorzuziehen, weil der Infinitiv ein Substantiv ist und deswegen – so er nicht verbalisiert ist – großgeschrieben wird.

Comment: Ich sage es nur ungern, aber ich finde es nicht gut, ‘ideologisches Getue’ anzubringen, insbesondere wenn deskriptive Grammatik dahintersteht/-stehen kann.

Comment: Anscheinend steht ja keine dahinter. Oder warum wird ›lieben + zu + Infinitiv‹ als falsch abgestempelt? Scheint nicht ganz so deskriptiv zu sein.

Comment: Deine Aussagen zur Interpunktion decken sich nicht mit den Rechtschreibregeln (§ 75 E1 und E2).

Comment: Hast du dir den Paragraphen oder nur die Ausnahmen durchgelesen? In den Erläuterungen steht, dass man ein Komma setzen _kann_, wenn es sich um einen Einschub handelt oder wenn Missverständnisse entstehen könnten.